# Generic Method in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to create Generic Method for the Post on Web Api Controller? Is it possible? if so is there any guidance for it.

Based on the command I need to segregate it how can it be done.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post<T>(T command) where T:ICommand{}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to derive the controller and specify the type.

Comment: How do you expect to determine the type?